# Dropdown form field

Tags: javascript

With JavaScript is it possible to have a drop down menu display a form field with an input type of text, instead of a list option? Could I get a jsfiddle demo example?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using JQuery to do this? Basically hide and show a div with all your input fields on it. This way you can create the illusion that it's a native dropdown. A standard dropdown does not support custom markup. There are aloso third party alternatives for "custom dropdowns" I suspect they are all implemented using some variation on what I suggested above...

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, but I doubt it is possible using a common `<select>` element. You should probably create a `<div>` consisting of several inputs (i.e. `<input type = "text">`).

Then you'll have a button (with a down-pointing arrow image :) ) and to its `onclick` event, you'll bind a function that shows your `<div>`. To hide the `<div>`, you can bind the hiding function to a click on the background or another click on your button.

To add some elegancy and create a dropdown effect while showing the `<div>`, you can set its height to 0 and then continually increment it with a timer.